# How to reduce the execution time while accessing data inside a Control (C# / .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, timer, real-time

I am working on a Windows forms application which contains a checkedListBox. I also have something like the following piece of code in my application (which is executed every 25 miliseconds by a Windows Forms "timer tick" event):

```
public Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew(); //global variable

someMethod()
{
    watch.Restart();

    if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0)) //executes wether the first item of the checkedListBox1 is checked
    {
        if (something1) {
            doSomething1();

            watch.Stop();
            double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        else {
            if (something2) {
                doSomething2();

                watch.Stop();
                double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            }
            else {
                doSomething3();

                watch.Stop();
                double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            }
        }
    }
    else //executes if not checked
    {
        if (something3) {
            doSomething4();

            watch.Stop();
            double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        else {
            doSomething5();

            watch.Stop();
            double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

        }
    }
}
```

While executing the code, when like this, it takes around 1-3 miliseconds to reach the `whatch.Stop()` inside the brackets containing `doSomething4()` or `doSomething5()`. However, when I execute something like this:

```
public Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew(); //global variable

someMethod()
{
watch.Restart();

/*if(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0))
                {
                    if (something1)
                    {
                        doSomething1();

                        watch.Stop();
                        double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (something2)
                        {
                            doSomething2();

                            watch.Stop();
                            double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        }
                        else
                        {    
                            doSomething3();

                            watch.Stop();
                            double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                        }
                    }
                } */ //when everything above and the first "if-else" pair are commented
//                else
//                {
                    if (something3)
                    {
                        doSomething4();

                        watch.Stop();
                        double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        doSomething5();

                        watch.Stop();
                        double elapsedSeconds = watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

                    }
//                }
}
```

...that is, without considering the most outer if and else, it takes around from 0.2 to 0.4 miliseconds! (Important note: the item inside the checkedListBox is always unchecked, and I am inserting the breakpoint to check the elapsed seconds on "random times" while the code is executing - instead of starting the execution with the breakpoint already inserted. I've debugged both codes plenty of times already...).

I know that there is a lot of code before reaching the `doSomething4()` or `doSomething5()` on the uncommented code, but the fact is that, logically, NOTHING is being executed inside `if(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0))` (since the checkbox is always unchecked).

How come a "simple" if() check could "ruin" the time execution and raise it to almost 10 times of its original value? (I know it should not be like this, because inside `doSomething4()` and `doSomething5()` there are plenty of if's and else's, and they by themselves do not raise the timer count that much...)

**EDIT (may/03/2020):**

So, I discovered that, apparently (as you can see on the comments below), what is causing this raise on the execution time is my application accessing its checkedListBox control and returning me the current boolean value.

This application of mine should execute as fast as possible... would there be a way to reduce this elapsed time, while still getting the `checkedListBox1().GetItemChecked()` value?

Comment: As a guess, it is not the if-statement itself that is slowing you down, but accessing the control. Try splitting it: first collect the result of GetItemChecked into a bool variable, then test that in the if

Comment: Bingo! A single ```bool checkedItem = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0);``` execution returned me 1.5 miliseconds. Please, post your answer!

(Is there a way to reduce this elapsed time? It is really important for my application to be the as fast as possible...).